# Does $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ make any sense in the case $\lambda_1$ is complex and $\lambda_2$ is positive?

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, page 120.

$\textbf{6.8 Proposition}$ Suppose $\mu,\lambda,\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are measures on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$, and $\mu$ is positive.

(c) If $\lambda_1\bot \mu$ and $\lambda_2\bot\mu$, then $\lambda_1+\lambda_2\,\bot\,\mu$.

If $\lambda_1$ is a complex measure and $\lambda_2$ is a positive measure, and there exists $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ such that $\lambda_1(E)$ is complex and not real and $\lambda_2(E)=\infty$, then what's $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)(E)$?

In the case, does $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ make any sense?

Comment: You have to handle the case of $\infty$ separately, but otherwise a real measure can be straightforwardly identified as a special case of a complex measure.

Comment: You're right, that does seem sloppy on Rudin's part.